# How to create a python dictionary only accepts uniques mutable objects

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, set, mutable

My problem can be divide in two parts. The first one is not allow more two equal values in the dictionary. For example, I have this class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __key(self):
        return tuple(self.__dict__[key] for key in self.__dict__)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self.__key() == other.__key()

        return NotImplemented
```

And I want to create and stored many objects in a dictionary like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = MyClass(1, 2, 3)
    obj2 = MyClass(3, 4, 5)
    obj3 = MyClass(1, 2, 3)

    myDict = {}  # empty dictionary

    myDict['a'] = obj1  # one key-value item
    myDict['b'] = obj2  # two key-value items
    myDict['c'] = obj3  # not allowed, value already stored
```

How to be sure that obj3 can't be stored in the dictionary ?

The second part of my problem is track when a mutable object change to avoid it be equal to the other values in the dictionary, i.e.:

```
    obj2.a = 1; obj2.b = 2; obj2.c = 3  # not allowed
```

I coded a class Container that inherit from the dictionary class, to store the values (with uniques keys), and I added a set, to track the values in the dictionary, i.e.:

```
class MyContainer(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.unique_objects_values = set()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:  # overwrite not allowed
            if value not in self.unique_object_values:  # duplicate objects values don't allowed
                super(MyContainer, self).__setitem__(key, value)
                self.unique_object_values.add(value)
            else:
                print("Object already exist. Object didn't stored")
        else:
            print("Key already exist. Object didn't stored")
```

And add parent member to `MyClass` to check if the values aren't already stored but I'm not pretty sure if a data structure already exist to solve my problem.

Comment: Implicitly, you have to do something similar. Because only keys can be unique, not the values, so what you have done is sort of the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Do you know if there is already a pattern (or idiom) to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Make another dictionary of the valued elements and check before adding the values to the original dictionary if it is present then don't add.